# Receiving bad value for attribute datetime with time-zone offset

Tags: html, datetime, timezone

I ran my html through the w3.org validator. There it mostly complained about bad values for the attribute datetime. But honestly i am uncertain where the problem is. I've followed the lead from this article http://www.brucelawson.co.uk/2012/best-of-time/ . A html line which was marked as an error due to the faulty datetime for the time-zone offset:

```
 <time class="workshops__date" datetime="2014-06-27">27.06.2014 (Fr)</time><time datetime="19:00+2:00">19:00</time>-<time datetime="23:00+2:00">23:00</time>
```

What would be the semantic correct way which would be accepted by the w3.org validator?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/time):

> **datetime**
>
> This attribute indicates the time and date of the element and must be a valid date with an optional time string.

It also links to [a w3.org page](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/datatypes.html#common.data.datetime) that describes the value as being compliant with [RFC 3339](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339).

Therefore, I would suggest:

```
<time datetime="2014-06-27T19:00:00+02:00">19:00</time>
```